# import csv to build several nodes all at once

Tags: nodes, importing-exporting

I'm new to Drupal. What's the easiest way to create multiple nodes on Drupal 7 all at once? I built a special content type and have the fields data in a CSV file.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is, you can using:

### [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds)

> Import or aggregate data as nodes, users, taxonomy terms or simple
> database records.
>
> - One-off imports and periodic aggregation of content
> - Import or aggregate RSS/Atom feeds
> - **Import or aggregate CSV files**
> - Import or aggregate OPML files
> - PubSubHubbub support
> - **Create nodes**, users, taxonomy terms or simple database records from import
> - Extensible to import any other kind of content
> - Granular mapping of input elements to Drupal content elements
> - Exportable configurations
> - Batched import for large files

[Video Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YXgjFRn7ty4)

Comment: thank you for the answer and helpful video tutorial. I installed the Feeds module and followed up the instructions. But when I click on 'Settings', options are not displayed. So I can't set up the 'content type'.

Comment: @MahdiSahebnasagh you mean [here](https://youtu.be/YXgjFRn7ty4?t=4m27s) ? If so, can you provide a screenshot? (there are multiple settings links) Beside **Node Processor** you clicked on setttings?

Comment: here's the [screenshot](http://tinypic.com/r/n16ng7/9) none of the settings links works.

Comment: i had downloaded beta version! I changed to an alpha version. now it's working... just took me 3 hours!

Comment: @MahdiSahebnasagh that is really odd, I've used that beta version with no problems. You can test it here https://simplytest.me/